# Changing .innerHTML after a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile and have a collapsible set.

When using a function to change its innerHTML it works just fine. Displaying the content inside as collapsibles.

```
<div id="doro" data-role="collapsibleset" data-iconpos="right" dir="rtl" align="right">
</div>
```

works when using:
     `document.getElementById("doro").innerHTML ='<div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Click me - Im collapsible!</h3>
        <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
      </div>'`

but when i try:

```
<input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="refreshPage();">
```

while:

```
function refreshPage(){
  var text = "<div data-role='collapsible'><h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1><p>I'm the expanded content.</p></div>";
  document.getElementById("doro").innerHTML = text;  
}
```

It changes the collapsible set I have into just text without the jqueryMobile css and javascript attached.

That's sort of what it looks like

```js
function refreshPage()
{
    var text = "<div data-role='collapsible'><h1>Click me</h1><p>I'm the new expanded content.</p></div>";
  document.getElementById("doro").innerHTML =text;  
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

   <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-display="overlay"> 
    <h2></h2>
      <form id="checkuser" name="checkuser" method="post" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all">
                <fieldset>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
                    </div>                                  
                    <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="refreshPage();">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
     </div>
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1></h1>
        <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext">Add</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="star" data-theme="a">Star button</a>
<p id="demo">
<div id="doro" data-role="collapsibleset" data-iconpos="right" dir="rtl" align="right">
   <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
        <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
      </div>
 </div></p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>My Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

this is a simplified example that won't work aswell, and I don't get why

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Collapsible Sets</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="name">  </div>
<script>
 document.getElementById("name").innerHTML ='<div data-role="collapsibleset"><div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Click me - Im collapsible!</h3><p>Im the expanded content.</p></div>';
function refreshPage(){ document.getElementById("name").innerHTML ='<div data-role="collapsibleset"><div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Click me - Im collapsible!</h3><p>Im the expanded content.</p></div>';}
</script>
<input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="refreshPage();">
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welkom on stackoverflow. When you ask a question, please provide sample code on jsfiddle or another platform, it makes it easier for us to check. :)

Comment: looks like you don't have all of the correct attributes on the div. put up a jsfiddle if you can

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/arao2Lj1/) fiddle. I have pasted your code given above [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/axrL1vwh/).

Comment: your fiddle doesn't work aswell, it does change the innerHTML but it doesn't make it a new collapsibleset

Comment: I noticed something when playing with the setTimeout attribute, the first innerHTML change occurs before the page is loaded and that's why it becomes an accordion. while the second happends after some event and it's therefore doesn't style it as an accordion. anyway past that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dynamically creating jQuery mobile widgets after the page has already been enhanced, you have to initialize the widgets yourself in one of the following ways:

Call [**.enhanceWithin()**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/) on the container element.

Call the individual widget intializer, e.g. .colapsibleset(), .collapsible(), etc.

For your example, you could do the following. Given a button and a container DIV with id="name":

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Collapsible Sets</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" >  
      <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />    
    <div id="name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On pagecreate, dynamically add the collapsibleset to the container and call enhanceWithin(). Also add a click handler to the button which calls refreshPage().  refreshPage() replaces the html in the container and again calls enhanceWithin().

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageone", function(){

    $("#name").html('<div data-role="collapsibleset"><div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Click me - Im collapsible!</h3><p>Im the expanded content.</p></div>').enhanceWithin();


    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        refreshPage();
    });
});


function refreshPage(){
    var text = '<div data-role="collapsibleset"><div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Click me - Im collapsible 2!</h3><p>Im the expanded content from button.</p></div>';

    $("#name").html(text).enhanceWithin();      
}
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/arao2Lj1/3/)**

Also, in your second code snippet, you are loading 2 different versions of jQuery. Use either 2.1 or 1.11 but not both.